# ¿Por qué no puedo ejecutar otras funciones fuera de esta?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este plugin de un calendario que me he bajado de una web y lo he introducido a mi página:

```js
function CALENDAR() {
  var wrap,
      label,
      months = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];

  function init(newWrap) {

    wrap = $(newWrap || '#cal');
    label = wrap.find('#label');

    wrap.find('#prev').bind('click.calender', function() {
      switchMonth(false);
    });

    wrap.find('#next').bind('click.calender', function() {
      switchMonth(true);
    });

    label.ready(function() {
      switchMonth(null, new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getFullYear());
    });

  }

  function switchMonth(next, month, year) {
    var curr = label.text().trim().split(' '),
        calendar, tempYear = parseInt(curr[1], 10);

    month = month || ((next) ? ((curr[0] === 'Diciembre') ? 0 : months.indexOf(curr[0]) + 1) : ((curr[0] === 'Enero') ? 11 : months.indexOf(curr[0]) - 1));
    year = year || ((next && month === 0) ? tempYear + 1 : (!next && month === 11) ? tempYear - 1 : tempYear);

    console.profile('createCal');
    calendar = createCal(year, month);
    console.profileEnd('createCal');

    $('#cal-frame', wrap)
      .find('.curr')
      .removeClass('curr')
      .addClass('temp')
      .end()
      .prepend(calendar.calendar())
      .find('.temp')
      .fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    label.text(calendar.label);
  }

  function createCal(year, month) {
    var day = 1,
        i,
        j,
        haveDays = true,
        startDay = new Date(year, month, day).getDay(),
        daysInMonth = [31, (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0)) ? 29 : 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
        calendar = [];

    if (createCal.cache[year]) {
      if (createCal.cache[year][month]) {
        return createCal.cache[year][month];
      }
    } else {
      createCal.cache[year] = {};
    }

    i = 0;

    while (haveDays) {
      calendar[i] = [];
      for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if (i === 0) {
          if (j === startDay) {
            calendar[i][j] = day++;
            startDay++;
          }
        } else if (day <= daysInMonth[month]) {
          calendar[i][j] = day++;
        } else {
          calendar[i][j] = '';
          haveDays = false;
        }
        if (day > daysInMonth[month]) {
          haveDays = false;
        }
      }
      i++;
    }

    if (calendar[5]) {
      for (i = 0; i < calendar[5].length; i++) {
        if (calendar[5][i] !== '') {
          calendar[4][i] = '<span>' + calendar[4][i] + '</span><span>' + calendar[5][i] + '</span>';
        }
      }
      calendar = calendar.slice(0, 5);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < calendar.length; i++) {
      calendar[i] = '<tr><td>' + calendar[i].join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>';
    }

    calendar = $('<table>' + calendar.join('') + '</table').addClass('curr');

    $('td:empty', calendar).addClass('nil');
    if (month === new Date().getMonth()) {
      $('td', calendar).filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === new Date().getDate().toString();
      }).addClass('today');
    }

    createCal.cache[year][month] = {
      calendar: function() {
        return calendar.clone();
      },
      label: months[month] + ' ' + year
    };

    return createCal.cache[year][month];
  }
  createCal.cache = {};

  return {
    init: init,
    switchMonth: switchMonth,
    createCal: createCal
  };

}

var cal = CALENDAR();
cal.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cal" class="relativo">
  <div class="header">
    <span class="left button" id="prev"> &lang; </span>
    <span class="left hook"></span>
    <span class="month-year" id="label">Octubre 2019</span>
    <span class="right hook"></span>
    <span class="right button" id="next"> &rang; </span>
  </div>
  <!-- <span id="inicio"></span> -->
  <table id="days">
    <td>Do</td>
    <td>Lu</td>
    <td>Ma</td>
    <td>Mi</td>
    <td>Ju</td>
    <td>Vi</td>
    <td>Sa</td>
  </table>
  <div id="cal-frame">
    <table class="curr" id="curr">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

El problema que tengo es que al ejecutar la función `calendar()` no se ejecutan otras funciones fuera de esta. Me explico, la idea es que al dar click en un día concreto del calendario, aparezca una ventana emergente donde puedas agregar una nota al día, como programar un evento. Ya hice ese código y funciona correctamente solo si la función `calendar()` no se ha activado.

Supongo que este problema es porque debo introducir el código que he creado dentro de la función `calendar()`, pero, como dije, no domino `JavaScript` o `jQuery` a tal profundidad como para saber qué debo hacer.

> Para los que vieron la pregunta anteriormente, ya resolví el problema que tenía con lo referente a cargar el calendario en el momento que se cargue la página.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el HTML sobre el que se aplica este código?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con ese código ;)

Comment: si solo ejecuta una función, es probable que tenga un error, puedes tener varias funciones pero si la primera tiene un error no ejecutara las siguientes, para ejecutar funciones fuera de ese script, tendrías que dar de alta el otro script al que quieres accesar desde el html que estas consumiendo

Comment: Pero si tuviese un error la consola me lo marcaría y esta no lo hace. Incluso, intenté poner mi código al inicio y el del calendario al final, pero no se lee

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir en tu código una de las funciones que dices que no se ejecutan?, para comprobar qué hacen dichas funciones y cómo las declaras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viendo tu respuesta, ya sé lo que te sucede. El código del calendario elimina los elementos que están en el `DOM` y crea unos nuevos cada vez que cambias de mes (y al inicio de la aplicación). Al eliminar los elementos, también eliminas cualquier evento que hayas añadido directamente a los mismos.

La solución que has encontrado, añade eventos a cada `td` de la tabla cada vez que se cambia de mes, lo cual no es óptimo. Lo mejor es que mediante [delegación de eventos](https://medium.com/@osmancea/delegaci%C3%B3n-de-eventos-del-dom-con-javascript-d28131d43686) crees un evento en la tabla (solo uno) que será ejecutado solo cuando ciertos hijos de la tabla disparen dicho evento y este se propague al padre. De esta manera tendrías solo un evento creado al inicio de tu aplicación que no importa si los `td` son creados dinámicamente funcionará todo el tiempo.

En `jQuery`, el segundo parámetro del método [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler), sirve para situar un selector que indicará qué elementos hijos serán los que delegarán el evento que sitúes como primer parámetro al elemento al que estás aplicando el método. Consulta el evento que he añadido al final del código (y que se encuentra fuera de `CALENDAR`):

```js
function CALENDAR() {
  var wrap, label,
    months = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];

  function init(newWrap) {
    wrap = $(newWrap || '#cal');
    label = wrap.find('#label');

    wrap.find('#prev').bind('click.calender', function() {
      switchMonth(false);
    });
    wrap.find('#next').bind('click.calender', function() {
      switchMonth(true);
    });
    label.ready(function() {
      switchMonth(null, new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getFullYear());
    });
  }

  function switchMonth(next, month, year) {
    var curr = label.text().trim().split(' '),
      calendar, tempYear = parseInt(curr[1], 10);

    month = month || ((next) ? ((curr[0] === 'Diciembre') ? 0 : months.indexOf(curr[0]) + 1) : ((curr[0] === 'Enero') ? 11 : months.indexOf(curr[0]) - 1));
    year = year || ((next && month === 0) ? tempYear + 1 : (!next && month === 11) ? tempYear - 1 : tempYear);

    console.profile('createCal');
    calendar = createCal(year, month);
    console.profileEnd('createCal');

    $('#cal-frame', wrap)
      .find('.curr')
      .removeClass('curr')
      .addClass('temp')
      .end()
      .prepend(calendar.calendar())
      .find('.temp')
      .fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    label.text(calendar.label);
  }

  function createCal(year, month) {
    var day = 1,
      i, j, haveDays = true,
      startDay = new Date(year, month, day).getDay(),
      daysInMonth = [31, (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0)) ? 29 : 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
      calendar = [];
    if (createCal.cache[year]) {
      if (createCal.cache[year][month]) {
        return createCal.cache[year][month];
      }
    } else {
      createCal.cache[year] = {};
    }
    i = 0;
    while (haveDays) {
      calendar[i] = [];
      for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if (i === 0) {
          if (j === startDay) {
            calendar[i][j] = day++;
            startDay++;
          }
        } else if (day <= daysInMonth[month]) {
          calendar[i][j] = day++;
        } else {
          calendar[i][j] = '';
          haveDays = false;
        }
        if (day > daysInMonth[month]) {
          haveDays = false;
        }
      }
      i++;
    }

    if (calendar[5]) {
      for (i = 0; i < calendar[5].length; i++) {
        if (calendar[5][i] !== '') {
          calendar[4][i] = '<span>' + calendar[4][i] + '</span><span>' + calendar[5][i] + '</span>';
        }
      }
      calendar = calendar.slice(0, 5);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < calendar.length; i++) {
      calendar[i] = '<tr><td>' + calendar[i].join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>';
    }

    calendar = $('<table>' + calendar.join('') + '</table').addClass('curr');

    $('td:empty', calendar).addClass('nil');
    if (month === new Date().getMonth()) {
      $('td', calendar).filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === new Date().getDate().toString();
      }).addClass('today');
    }

    createCal.cache[year][month] = {
      calendar: function() {
        return calendar.clone();
      },
      label: months[month] + ' ' + year
    };

    return createCal.cache[year][month];
  }
  createCal.cache = {};

  return {
    init: init,
    switchMonth: switchMonth,
    createCal: createCal
  };

}

var calendar = CALENDAR();
calendar.init();

function abrir() {
  console.log(this.innerText);
}

$('#cal').on('click', 'tbody tr td', abrir);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cal" class="relativo">
  <div class="header">
    <span class="left button" id="prev"> &lang; </span>
    <span class="left hook"></span>
    <span class="month-year" id="label">Octubre 2019</span>
    <span class="right hook"></span>
    <span class="right button" id="next"> &rang; </span>
  </div>
  <!-- <span id="inicio"></span> -->
  <table id="days">
    <td>Do</td>
    <td>Lu</td>
    <td>Ma</td>
    <td>Mi</td>
    <td>Ju</td>
    <td>Vi</td>
    <td>Sa</td>
  </table>
  <div id="cal-frame">
    <table class="curr" id="curr">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vaaalee, ya entiendo. Tienes toda la razón. Gracias por optimizar el código o guiarme a la acción más adecuada

Answer (score 1):

¿Cómo haces referencia a esta función en tu página?

Porque si lo único que deseas es llamar a esta función inmediatamente se carga la página podrías probar con:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    calendar();

});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Ya lo intenté de esa forma y no me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Vale, ya pude resolver el problema haciendo algunas pruebas:

```
function switchMonth(next, month, year) {
  var curr = label.text().trim().split(' '), calendar, tempYear = parseInt(curr[1], 10);

  month = month || ((next) ? ((curr[0] === 'Diciembre') ? 0 : months.indexOf(curr[0]) + 1) : ((curr[0] === 'Enero') ? 11 : months.indexOf(curr[0]) - 1));
  year = year || ((next && month === 0) ? tempYear + 1 : (!next && month === 11) ? tempYear - 1 : tempYear);

  console.profile('createCal');
  calendar = createCal(year, month);
  console.profileEnd('createCal');

  $('#cal-frame', wrap)
    .find('.curr')
    .removeClass('curr')
    .addClass('temp')
    .end()
    .prepend(calendar.calendar())
    .find('.temp')
    .fadeIn('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); });
   label.text(calendar.label);

    function abrir() {
      //Agregar acción
    }

    $('.curr tbody tr td').on('click',abrir);
  }
```

Las funciones se deben agregar aquí dentro, ya que la función `switchMonth()` nos dice qué parte del calendario se está mostrando e interactúa dinamicamente con la parte del calendario que contiene los días. O al menos, ese es el porqué que yo deduzco.

Comment: No hace falta declarar la función `abrir` dentro de la función `switchMonth`, puedes declararla fuera también y te debería funcionar. Lo que te sucede es que el método `switchMonth` que corre al inicio y cada vez que cambias de mes, elimina los elementos (`td`) y crea otros nuevos, eliminando cualquier evento que hayas añadido directamente en ellos. En la respuesta que te he dado te indico la solución.